# Module for HR and vacancies

Tags: 7

Is there a module for Drupal that can be used for job postings, with specific access limited to people from HR / system admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your all requirements by installing [Recruiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) Drupal distribution.

> Recruiter is a Drupal distribution for building Drupal based
>   e-recruitment platforms. Users can register either as recruiter and
>   post job classifieds or they can register as applicants and fill out
>   their resume. A faceted search helps users to find jobs and possible
>   job candidates.

Comment: Thank you.  I am concerned with this module however as it appears usage is low, and has in fact reduced over time.  Are there any more popular modules available?  I couldn't find any on drupal.org.